# Cannot receive UDP packet from FPGA

Tags: udp, fpga, ethernet

I want to send messages from my FPGA device to my computer. I don't know how to use SOC and write linux drivers so I packet UDP frames without using an OS. My IP is fixed at 192.168.0.1 with mask 255.255.255.0 and MAC address is 10-C3-7B-44-FA-8A. I found that wireshark can recognize my UDP packets and shows the IP address and port is all right but my applications can not.

[Wireshark snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQpHs.jpg)

I tried two applications that written in python and matlab as follows,

python:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
s.bind((192.168.0.1, 4096))
buf=s.recvfrom(65536)
```

Matlab:

```
u = udp('192.168.0.2',4096,'LocalPort',4096,'LocalHost','192.168.0.1');
fopen(u)
buf=fread(u,1000)
```

Both of applications prompt timeout after execute the last line of their code.

Something wrong?

Comment: What's the IP of your FPGA?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If not you should post a _small_ Wireshark log in .pcap or .pcapng format rather than a screenshot. From what you can see on the screenshot, it is very close to working - the physical layer and MAC appears good which is a lot of the hard stuff.

Comment: The IP of FPGA is 192.168.0.2. It never works. The platform has changed so I have to spend some time to recover it and get .pcap file as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can see packets with Wireshark, seems to be an application issue. [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) has excellent tools for packet manipulation.

The python code below should print packets whose destination IP is 192.168.0.1 (based on [Scapy Doc](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#simplistic-arp-monitor))

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import *

def monitor_cb(pkt):
    if IP in pkt and pkt[IP].dst == '192.168.0.1':
        return pkt.show()

sniff(prn=monitor_cb, store=0)
```

Notice it needs to be run as root.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I found my problem and now my board can send udp packets to my MATLAB. My checksum in the head of IP packet was wrong and now I have corrected it.